# Is there a way to bookmark all tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way to bookmark all tabs in Chrome?

I seem to remember this being out of the box in Firefox and I'd love to get the same functionality in Chrome.  Perhaps it's an issue because each tab is a separate process?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Update: Google Chrome implemented a bookmark all tabs functionality. All you do is right click on any tab button (strip) and you will see an option to bookmark it or all tabs.

<del>Yes, there is a chrome extension that you can download that would bookmark all tabs via keyboard shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+D) You can download the extension [here](http://m0interactive.com/archives/2009/10/02/google_chrome_bookmark_all_tabs_extension.html):</del>

Comment: You could update your answer since it's now possible to do that.

Answer (score 16):

It's now without any extension CTRL+SHIFT+D

Comment: Works for me in Mozilla Firefox aswell (same combination). great advice, thank you AMgdy.