# Importing Bookmarks from a Text File (to any browser/website)

Tags: browser

I have dozens of text files containing around 60 url's each, accumulated over years of browsing on multiple computers. I wish to import these into *any* browser, to allow me to then use cross-browser importing. My ultimate goal is to then import the bookmarks to somewhere like delicious, which will automatically tag the links, allowing me to sort each page by subject.

The closest I've managed to find is:
[Import bookmarks to firefox from txt file](https://superuser.com/questions/103615/import-bookmarks-to-firefox-from-txt-file)

However while this plugin imports from a text file, it has no correlation with Firefox's bookmarks, and only allows you to export back to csv/txt files.

I understand that the problem of importing from text files is that bookmarks need a *Title*, and so I wish to use a given pages existing title.

I've been unable to find any such tool on the net.

Comment: Using the existing Titles of webpages may not be a very good choice as the bookmark names, as they are frequently ridiculously long, and amount to advertising blurbs.

Answer (score 4):

[Linkman](http://www.outertech.com/en/bookmark-manager) can do this.  First, import the URLs using the "any file" option (just looks for URLs) then run the "Retrieve missing names from web pages" in the Bookmarks menu.

I have the paid version and I'm not sure if the free version has the import option I mentioned.  I'd be happy to convert the text files and give you the resulting file that could be used to import into any browser's bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty clever answer [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=470494), that I'll modify a bit.

1. Open your **text file** of links, *one per line* in a browser.
2. Hit F12 and use javascript in the console to open each in a new window (you might have to override your pop-up blocker).

[image: Sorry, can't install Skitch at work. MSPaint it is!]

`Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.outerText.split("\n"), function (a) { window.open(a) });`

3. [Add all tabs as bookmarks](https://superuser.com/a/50660/114388).
4. Profit.

Worked in Chrome. I think that's give or take what you want, right?

Comment: Suggestion: Use `document.body.innerText` to be more compatible. The innerText works in other browsers as well, unlike outerText that does not work in Firefox. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

created a bash script that does this:
https://github.com/harshvchawla/convert-links-to-bookmarks

a `link.com` when converted to format `<DT><A href="link.com">Title</A>` is importable so the script does that

Comment: Thanks you! This is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Make a big file with one url per line, then copy the url list and then paste it in the bookmark window. Done.

The only downside is the bookmark names will be the urls and not the actual page titles.

Comment: @downvoters please elaborate on why this is not an acceptable solution